# Самый частотный символ который вообще существует

Tags: python

На вход программе подается строка текста. Напишите программу, которая выводит на экран символ, который появляется наиболее часто. Формат входных данных На вход программе подается строка текста. Текст может содержать строчные и заглавные буквы английского и русского алфавита, а также цифры. Формат выходных данных Программа должна вывести символ, который появляется наиболее часто. Примечание 1. Если таких символов несколько, следует вывести последний по порядку символ. Примечание 2. Следует различать заглавные и строчные буквы, а также буквы русского и английского алфавита.

```
s = input()
total = 0
for i in s:
    total += s.count(i)
print(total)
#или print max(total)
```

Я сделала вот так, но не понимаю что дальше делать, простите за мою глупость

Answer (score 2):

можно сделать так (это неоптимально по скорости конечно):

1. получить из текста только уникальные символы (через множество)

   ```
    letters = set(text)
   ```
2. пройтись по уникальным символам и подчитать их кол-во в тексте

   ```
    for letter in letters:
        count = text.count(letter)
   ```
3. результат записать в виде словаря к примеру или списку кортежей

   ```
    (letter, count)
   ```
4. найти в этом списке максимальный элемент

   ```
    max_value = max(arr, key=lambda obj: obj[1])
   ```
5. выбрать из списка через filter все такие элементы

   ```
    all_max_elements = list(filter(lambda obj: obj[1] == max_value, arr))
   ```
6. найти последний символ

Comment: Большое спасибо вам!

Answer (score 1):

```py
string = input()

# создаем список с символами и их количеством в строке
letters = [(letter, string.count(letter)) for letter in set(string)]

# выводим самый частотный символ
print(max(letters, key=lambda x: x[1])[0])
```

Comment: Test input:
aaaabbc
Correct output:
a

Your code output:
('a', 4)

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы программа напечатала только самый частотный символ и чтобы не было скобок и сколько таких символов там есть, я буду очень благодарна если вы поможете мне!

Comment: Извините, не заметил этого, когда писал. Поправил

Comment: Все сработало, но есть одно НО....

Comment: Примечание 1. Если таких символов несколько, следует вывести последний по порядку символ. Можно еще эту часть добавить в код? Простите за мою глупость((